# How can I access a single cell from a range of cells stored in a series.xvalues?

Tags: vba, excel

The backstory of why I'm trying to do this is because I need to place callout labels at the peaks of local maximas, but the values need to be the x-values and not the y-values.

I have tried doing this multiple way, most recently like this:

```
Dim c As Chart

Set c = sht.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

With c
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .SeriesCollection(8).Name = "Data Labels"
    .SeriesCollection(8).XValues = Range(sht.Cells(start, 2), sht.Cells(ender, 2))
    .SeriesCollection(8).Values = Range(sht.Cells(start, 9), sht.Cells(ender, 9))
    .SeriesCollection(8).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
End With

For i = 1 To c.SeriesCollection(8).Points.count

    c.SeriesCollection(8).Points(i).HasDataLabel = True
    c.SeriesCollection(8).Points(i).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
    c.SeriesCollection(8).Points(i).DataLabel.Format.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangularCallout
    c.SeriesCollection(8).Points(i).DataLabel.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
error--->c.SeriesCollection(8).Points(i).DataLabel.Text = c.SeriesCollection(8).XValues.Cells(i, 1)

Next i
```

This returns an error "Object Required"

I have also tried

```
c.SeriesCollection(8).Points(i).DataLabel.Text = c.SeriesCollection(8).XValues(i)
c.SeriesCollection(8).Points(i).DataLabel.Text = c.SeriesCollection(8).XValues(i).value
```

And A few more that I am most likely forgetting off of the top of my head.

What I really want and need is to retrieve the value located in the "i" position of c.SeriesCollection(8).XValues

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is `c` here and which line gives you the error?

Comment: c is a chart and the line c.SeriesCollection(8).Points(i).DataLabel.Text = c.SeriesCollection(8).XValues.Cells(i, 1) gives the error. Sorry about that I will add that to the original post

Comment: Try `c.SeriesCollection(8).XValues(i)` - `XValues` can be set from a `Range` object, but doesn't *return* a range when you access its value.

Comment: Unfortunately that was the first thing I tried. It yields a "Run-time error '451': Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XValues returns a Variant array (not a Range), but for some reason this throws an error:

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues(1)
```

> Run-time error '451':Property let procedure not defined and property
>   get procedure did not return an object

Whereas this works just fine:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim v, i
    v = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues

    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        Debug.Print "Point#" & i, v(i)
    Next i


End Sub
```